# Show that $\Sigma w_n$ is uniformly convergent on $]0,1[$

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that if $w_n=(-1)^nx^n(1-x)$ on $]0,1[$, then $\Sigma w_n$ is uniformly convergent on $]0,1[$.

My attempt: We can show that $\Sigma w_n$ is absolutely convergent on $]0,1[$, and conclude that $\Sigma w_n$ converges uniformly.
I know that this function has a maximum at $n/(n+1)$, but I can't use *Weierstrass M-Test* since $\Sigma n/(n+1)$ do not converges.

Can you guys give me any hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $w_n(x) = x^n(1-x)(-1)^n $. Let $a_n(x) = x^n(1-x)$, $b_n(x) = (-1)^n $

So that $w_n(x) = a_n(x)\cdot b_n(x)$

(1): As we see, for every $N \in \mathbb N$,$ | \sum_{n=1}^N b_n(x) | \le 2 $.

(2:) Moreover, for any fixed $x \in (0,1)$, sequence $(a_n(x))_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is monotone:

Clearly $a_{n+1}(x) - a_{n}(x) = x^n(1-x)(x-1) = -x^n(1-x)^2 < 0 $ for any $ (n,x) \in \mathbb N \times (0,1)$

(3): Finally, sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N} $ converges uniformly to $0$.

To see that, note for any fixed $x \in (0,1)$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x) = 0$.

And looking at maximum, we have $a_n'(x) = nx^{n-1}(1-x) - x^n = x^{n-1}(n-nx-x)$, which is equal to $0$, when $n = x(n+1)$, so $x = \frac{n}{n+1} $

By that $ d_n = \sup_{x \in (0,1)} |a_n(x) - 0| = a_n(\frac{n}{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n+1}(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n$.

Since $(1-\frac{1}{n+1})^n \to \frac{1}{e}$ and $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, we get $\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n = 0$, so the convergence is uniform

Taking together (1),(2) and (3) we can use Dirichlet Test for Uniform Convergence. So $\sum w_n$ converges uniformly on $(0,1)$

Answer (score 1):

Note that$$(\forall n\in\mathbb N):\max_{x\in(0,1)}\bigl\lvert f_n(x)\bigr\rvert=\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n.$$Since$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac n{n+1}\right)^n=0,$$the convergence is uniform.

Answer (score 1):

The partial sums can be computed explicitly : $S_N=\frac {(1-(-x)^{N+1})(1-x)} {1+x} $. This tends to $\frac {1-x} {1+x}$ uniformly. To see this note that $\frac {|x|^{N+1} (1-x)} {1+x} \to 0$ uniformly: this quantity is $<\epsilon/(1+x) <\epsilon$ if $x \geq 1-\epsilon$ and it is $\leq (1-\epsilon)^{N+1}$ if $x \leq 1-\epsilon$. Of course, $(1-\epsilon)^{N+1} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.